# bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb -- RubyonRails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bundle, rubymine

I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial and I'm getting the following error in section 3.2.1 when I run:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

I've seen similar errors posted but none exactly the same.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Error:

```
/Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:791:in `<': compared with non class/module (TypeError)
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:791:in `safe_include'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:785:in `block in configure_group'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:783:in `each'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:783:in `configure_group'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/world.rb:47:in `configure_group'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:290:in `set_it_up'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:241:in `subclass'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:228:in `describe'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
    from /Users/michaeltro/RubymineProjects/sample_project/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /Users/michaeltro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'enter code here
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Routes.rb:

```
SampleProject::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/help"

end
```

static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static Pages" do
  describe "Home page" do
    it "should have the content 'Sample Project'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample Project')
    end
  end
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
  config.include Capybara: :DSL
end
```

Comment: Change `config.include Capybara: :DSL` to `config.include Capybara::DSL` in your `spec_helper`.

Comment: That extra space was the problem.  Removed it and now it works!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your **static_pages_spec.rb** file like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end

    it "should have the base title" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App")
    end

    it "should not have a custom page title" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).not_to have_title('| Home')
    end
  end
end
```